# How to process errors in Rust within a match?

Tags: rust

Here's some code. I'd like to match on:

```
enum Option {
    Aoption,
    Boption,
    KeyError,
}

let key = "foo";

let key = match key {
    "a" => Aoption
    "b" => Boption
     _ => KeyError    // how can I throw an error here?
};

// unclear to me if I can somehow wrap the enum in a Result or Some?
key.unwrap();

// can I use a Result somehow? If so, how do I wrap my enum or string in a result?
Ok(s) => s,
Err(_) => Err
```

Comment: What do you mean by "throw an error". You mean, tell the calling code that something went badly? A `Result<Option, Error>` could do that, yes. Otherwise, we can make the code panic when something is really out of hands.

Comment: Yes, I want to terminate the program because something is wrong if key is not "a" or "b".

Comment: The use panic! ?

Comment: Thanks. My issue is I don't understand how to wrap a string in some structure that support panic!

Comment: Possibly refer to [the chapter on error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) and update your question with specifics? There are some examples there that show `panic()` and `unwrap()` usage, both of which can terminate your application if need be.

Comment: @turtle you need a converter trait to achieve that, it is best to use `TryFrom` trait, here is an example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e0249779b36e74616ec3e2da9228188, for an alternative you can use [extension traits](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0445-extension-trait-conventions.html#what-is-an-extension-trait), also an example:  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=48af0802d9b77c58ac8f0a5a11836b8d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to process errors in Rust within a match?

Either returning a `Result`, an `Option` or panicking.

Normally the `enum` would only have valid states and then have it wrapped in a `Result` or `Option`. But it is certainly possible to put errors like `KeyError` in your `enum`.

`panic!` is possible since it never returns (`!`):

```
match x {
    0 => A,
    1 => B,
    _ => panic!(),
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of `panic!` because I thought its return type would be different that A or B.

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, that is the magic of the `!` type.